# asp.net core 2.0 was working but now shows HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi8tM.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxEUJ.png)I created an .net API that fetches data from the server and stores the data in a json file every 2 hours, it work perfectly fine for the past few days but now it displays "HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway", is there anyway i can fix this ?

Comment: Please add your config and code samples.

Comment: what have you change ?

Comment: @programtreasures , I didn't change anything, came in yesterday morning and it started showing me such.

Comment: @Sunil click on the link to view the screen shots

Comment: @NkosinathiMokotong It is seems requestTimeout exception in config add `requestTimeout=00:10:00` in `<aspnetCore ` tag

Comment: @programtreasures I am using IIS, so this means I have to create the web.config file ?

Comment: yes, refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/aspnet-core-module